# Solid vertical line passing through cells in table

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

I am attempting to create a table with the following layout:

[image]

and the code generating the table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{c|cccc}
        0 & -69.2 & 0.549 & 40.1 & $\vert$ \\
        0.5 & -68.2 & 0.551 & 38.5 & $\vert$ \\
        1 & -74.1 & 0584 & 38.3 & 0.0418 \\
        1.5 & -74.9 & 0.576 & 37.7 & $\vert$ \\
        2 & -74.1 & 0.571 & 39.7 & $\vert$ \\
        2.5 & -75.5 & 0.566 & 45.2 & $\vert$ \\
        3 & -73.6 & 0.565 & 48.4 & $\vert$ \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

(Note: I have omitted the header). The dashed vertical line above and below the value 0.0418 should indicate that the value applies to all rows. It is simply made manually by me putting a '$\vert$' in each cell. I think, however, that it looks awful. Instead, I would like the lines above and below the value 0.0418 to be solid and extend through all cells above and below the cell containing 0.0418.

All help is appreciated! :)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please always provide complete small document, which we can copy and test on our computers. Document preamble contain valuable information about your document, which are now hidden form us. Also, why we should write from scratch a test document, when you have already done?

Comment: Duly noted! I have edited the post accordingly, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably not the best solution but it does the job

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}{c|cccc|c}
            0 & -69.2 & 0.549 & 40.1 & ~~ & \\
            0.5 & -68.2 & 0.551 & 38.5 &  & \\
            1 & -74.1 & 0584 & 38.3 & \multicolumn{2}{r}{0.0418}  \\
            1.5 & -74.9 & 0.576 & 37.7 & &\\
            2 & -74.1 & 0.571 & 39.7 & &\\
            2.5 & -75.5 & 0.566 & 45.2 &  &\\
            3 & -73.6 & 0.565 & 48.4 &  &\\
        \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

The key is, that you use the `\multicolumn` command. With the `~`, which represents a space, you can shift the position of the vertical line.

[image]

Comment: Since you not provide an MWE, it is not possible to test your solution ...

Comment: Updated it now. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: Thank you. Simple and nice solution (+1). You may consider to ad image of table produced by your MWE :-)

Comment: Thank you for the great solution, Steradiant! I was hoping to find a more "automatic" solution - but this one should work just as fine! :)

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht] % <---
    \centering    % <---
        \begin{tabular}{c|cccc}
            0 & -69.2 & 0.549 & 40.1                    & \rdelim{]}{7}{1cm}[0.0418] \\
            0.5 & -68.2 & 0.551 & 38.5                  &  \\
            1 & -74.1 & 0584 & 38.3                     & \\
            1.5 & -74.9 & 0.576 & 37.7                  &  \\
            2 & -74.1 & 0.571 & 39.7                    &  \\
            2.5 & -75.5 & 0.566 & 45.2                  &  \\
            3 & -73.6 & 0.565 & 48.4                    &  \\
        \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

**WITH TIKZ**

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand\tikzmark[1]{\tikz[remember picture,overlay] \coordinate (#1);}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht] % <---
    \centering    % <---
        \begin{tabular}{c|cccc}
            0 & -69.2 & 0.549 & 40.1                    & \tikzmark{a} \\
            0.5 & -68.2 & 0.551 & 38.5                  &  \\
            1 & -74.1 & 0584 & 38.3                     & \\
            1.5 & -74.9 & 0.576 & 37.7                  &  \\
            2 & -74.1 & 0.571 & 39.7                    &  \\
            2.5 & -75.5 & 0.566 & 45.2                  &  \\
            3 & -73.6 & 0.565 & 48.4                    & \tikzmark{b} \\
        \end{tabular}

    \tikz[remember picture,overlay]
    {\draw ([yshift=2ex]a) -- (b) node[xshift=0.7em,midway,fill=white] {0.0418};}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Since you not provide an MWE, it is not possible to test your solution ...

Comment: edited with MWE please

Comment: Only second solution answered OP problem. Please make MWE really minimal. I suspect that most of loaded packages in preamble are irrelevant to the OP problem.

Comment: edited the irrelevant packages please

Comment: I took a liberty and delete all irrelevant packages in your second answer and correct table placement options and replace `center` environment with `\centering` command. If you not liked this, please revert your answer in the previous state.

Answer (score 1):

As supplement to [@js bibra](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/546841/solid-vertical-line-passing-through-cells/546847#546847) answer (+1). Used are `array` package and table environment (for correct minus symbols and for `w` column type} and TikZ library `tikzmark` (all for exercises and variety of answers):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]   % <---
\[
    \begin{array}{l|ccc w{c}{6ex}}
    0   & -69.2 & 0.549 & 40.1  & \tikzmarknode{A}{\vphantom{0}}   \\
    0.5 & -68.2 & 0.551 & 38.5  &   \\
    1   & -74.1 & 0.584 & 38.3  &   \\
    1.5 & -74.9 & 0.576 & 37.7  &   \\
    2   & -74.1 & 0.571 & 39.7  &   \\
    2.5 & -75.5 & 0.566 & 45.2  &   \\
    3   & -73.6 & 0.565 & 48.4  & \tikzmarknode{B}{} \\
    \end{array}
%
    \tikz[remember picture,overlay]
    {\draw (A.north) -- node[fill=white] {0.0418} (B);}
\]
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

*Note*: For above result the MWE should be compiled twice!

Comment: Thanks for the (in my opinion) clarifying answer to @js bibra's answer :) Also a viable option, though it requires some packages.

Comment: @Ankerstjerne, are your document not need any package? Using them is not a sin ;-). BTW, instead said "thank you" you can up-vote answer :-)

Comment: Right! I unfortunately do not have enough reputation to do so - it appears to require 15 points.. :)

Comment: @Ankerstjerne, i didn't check your reputation (I only up-vote your question, unfortunately others write only answers ). Then next time :-)

Answer (score 0):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`. The environment is similar to the classical `{tabular}` (of `array`) but creates PGF/Tikz nodes under the cells and rows. So, it's possible (in the `\CodeBefore`) to use those nodes to draw with Tikz whatever rule you want.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{NiceTabular}{c|cccc}
\CodeBefore
  \tikz \draw (1-|5.5) -- (last-|5.5) ; 
\Body
0 & -69.2 & 0.549 & 40.1 \\
0.5 & -68.2 & 0.551 & 38.5 \\
1 & -74.1 & 0584 & 38.3 & \colorbox{white}{0.0418} \\
1.5 & -74.9 & 0.576 & 37.7 \\
2 & -74.1 & 0.571 & 39.7 \\
2.5 & -75.5 & 0.566 & 45.2 \\
3 & -73.6 & 0.565 & 48.4 \\
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes).

[image: Output of the above code]